# Linux Assembly Debugger

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly

I need a debugger for assembly on Linux. I am extremely surprised by the LACK of debuggers out there for Linux! It should have various features, such as showing the registers and what not. I would use GDB, however it isn't exactly friendly with NASM.

I would rather have the debugger have intel syntax however I can make a sacrifice.

I have tried kdb, gdb/ddd, and ald. Does anyone know of any else? Don't recommend strace, because I am going beyond syscalls!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you mean when you say that gdb is not friendly with NASM. The thing is that gdb uses AT&T notation for displaying assembler. NASM uses Intel notation. There are a couple of differences, which you can find on Google.

You can configure gdb to display assembler using Intel notation. The command is:

`set disassembly-flavor intel`

Programs that you've tried, kdb, ddd and friends are all gdb front-ends, i.e. they present you different UI while use gdb as their back-end.

I think your best and perhaps the only reasonable option is gdb. Another option is to write a debugger yourself, but this is quite complicated.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, kdb is not a gdb front-end, but ddd is. I used kdb a couple of times. One advantage that is has over any other debugger is that it is kernel level debugger. I.e. it can shut down entire system, while you're debugging it. Yet it's power is also it's weakness - because it is kernel level, it is very limited.

Comment: GDB is sort of a pain to manage. It's great for C, but trying a command that would be beneficial to ASM debugging, such as disas main or _start, tells you no symbol table is loaded. Unless I'm missing something, I'll check if NASM allows compilation with symbols.

Comment: I understand what you mean. GDB is certainly not user friendly. However, my experience with it is that usually when I need something from it, it takes some time but eventually I find a way to do what I want.

Comment: Very well then, how would I go about setting a breakpoint at "main" in a executable without symbols? It just seems a tad bit more complicated then it should be.

Comment: Well, find a way to get symbols into your executable. This will make your life much easier. Otherwise, use addresses. You can set a breakpoint at certain address in the code. Use break *<address>

Comment: If you have no symbols then how do you want to refer to `main`?

Comment: It seems like I've solved the problem with GDB. With NASM you have to set flag -f as elf, then use ld and make sure that symbols aren't stripped by default. Thanks for the intel syntax command!

Answer (score 3):

Could any of the debuggers listed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=608123&highlight=ollydbg) help you?

Comment: Evan's Debugger is quite nice; but I'm compiling 32 bit binaries on a 64 machine!

Answer (score 3):

I'm really understand the [@Saustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507033/saustin)'s question because I was looking for a Linux Assembly Debugger too, which means the possibility for create breakpoints, run step by step, see the registers on real time, go back (backtrace) or go forward, see the data in memory, etc,.

The solution is use properly [DDD](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/)/[GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

First at all it is the screenshot show how it looks.

[image: ddd debugging an ASM file]

---

It needs some special requirement:

- When you create the executable file use the special flag `-F stabs` in `nasm` like this:

Linux command line:

```sh
nasm -f elf -F stabs hello.asm -o hello_stabs.o
ld -m elf_i386 hello_stabs.o -o hello_stabs
```

- Then you run your the debug normally like: `ddd hello_stabs`
- Enjoy!

The option `-F stabs`, tells the assembler to include debugging information in the output file. DDD and [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/stabs.html) use the [STABS](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/stabs_1.html) debugging format.

---

Source and good short tutorial:

[The Data Display Debugger (DDD), A Quick Start Guide](http://www.cs.smith.edu/~jfrankli/231f13/231/doc/quickstart.html)

Comment: GDB works better with `nasm -g -Fdwarf`.  It can use STABS, but DWARF is the more modern format.  See also the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for debugging tips with GDB and `strace`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with GDB then you may try [PEDA](https://github.com/longld/peda) extension, for me it mix the commandline experience with GUI

[image]

Comment: Fantastic extension! Turns gdb into a hardcore tool.