# Assembly MOV doesn't work, Debug for Linux and INT code list

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, mov, interruptions

I have a problem here...
I'm using debug (in cmd/ms-dos) to learn some things and to peforme some commands... I set **AX to 1234** and **DX to ABCD**.
So, I did '**-a 100**' to register a instruction, I did: mov ah,dl
And them "**-g**" (because I set an interruption) or "-g 102" to peforme the instruction and stop before 102 offset (if I not set the interruption).
When I peform **-r** to show me the registers values, they remain unchanged, this should be **AX:CD34**, but **AX is 1234** yet, looks like the MOV command doesn't works... what am I doing wrong?

http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/4866/movdxdldoesntworks.png

(sorry for the link, I need reputation to post image)

I also would like to know if exists something like Windows Debug to Linux, I mean, I have nasm and yasm in my Linux installation (Debian-based), but it's just a compiler, I need to write the code into a file, and compile it to run, we have some "emulator" or "debug" tool for ASM in Linux? Like the Debug windows software in the picture above?

The last thing, sorry to make the message so long with 3 questions, but I don't want to "flood" with a lot of topics, so, my last question is where can I find some kind of list of interruptions? I would like to find some list or manual with machine code functions. In Peter Norton's book, for example, when I have "02h" in the "AH" register, I tell to DOS to print one character in the screen, and he said "if you want to find a list of functions, you can look your DOS manual", well, I can't find this dos manual (in linux we can type "man" and we have manuals for everything), the windows "help" function is only a list for simple commands, not a real manual like the unix "man".

I try to find it in google, but every "DOS manual" did I found only show me simple functions like "cd, dir, format, time, blablabla", nothing real technical about the system or something... Can you help-me in find some complete list of "AH" commands and functions?
I know INT 18h is for run Basic and INT 19h restarts the computer (a guy said to me, 18h for him doesn't run basic but restarts the computer instead of INT 19h). I also find 2 or 3 more occurrences in Google, but not a "complete" list, someone have it?

Thanks for the help, patience and attention, I love you! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it again with:

```
.g=cs:0100 0102
```

http://www.armory.com/~rstevew/Public/Tutor/Debug/debug-manual.html

.........

**RBIL**: Ralf Browns x86/MSDOS Interrupt List

http://www.pobox.com/~ralf

http://www.pobox.com/~ralf/files.html

ftp://ftp.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/ralf/pub/

Dirk

Comment: Thanks Dirk! Now I worked fine!
I don't know why need to uso =cs:0100 0102, but it works, I will read the manual to see if I found a explanation!
Thanks for the links, they looks broken to me but with the name I can find the files, user2357782 put the same list (I think) also.
Really thanks man! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say why it does not work in your debugger.
Did you try to just type this in your program and put breakpoint at the end of it to see the result?

Here is an answer to the question about linux debugger (they recommend GDB):
[Linux Assembly Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761171/linux-assembly-debugger)

For the third question here you have a good source of info about interrupts: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/ralf/pub/WWW/files.html

In case link gets outdated search for "Ralf Brown's Interrupt List"

Comment: One of the Linux debuggers mentioned is Terry Loveall's. He took Patrick Alken's `ALD` and integrated some Nasm code to give it an `-a` command. Terry's "Coughing Up A Furball" page seems to be gone, but I have a copy here: http://home.myfairpoint.net/fbkotler/debug-0.0.21.tgz Gdb is probably "better" (`-F dwarf` switch to Nasm may help), but this is "like DEBUG"... if that's a "feature". :)

Comment: Really thanks to user2357782 and Frank Kotler, I will try it. Thanks for the attention. Cheers!
The Interrupt list is awesome! Thanks! ;D